# Another way to get all the images in an excel file using Apache POI

Tags: excel, apache-poi

Is there another way to read and get all the pictures in an excel file by not using this `.getAllPictures()` method?

Comment: I don't think so. Why do you need another method?

Comment: because I cant get all the images in excel by that method